# insert </br> after comma with php

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I array text from custom field "black, grey, white" with this code:

```
<?php global $wp_query; $postid = $wp_query->post->ID; echo get_post_meta($postid, 'colors', true); ?>
```

I want show me like this:

```
black</br>
grey</br>
white
```

It's possible with PHP? Many thanks

Comment: `str_replace(",", ",<br>", $string);`

Comment: For the record, it's `<br />`, not `</br>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use str_replace():

```
echo str_replace(",", "<br />", get_post_meta($postid, 'colors', true));
```

Comment: But how put <?php global $wp_query; $postid = $wp_query->post->ID; echo get_post_meta($postid, 'colors', true); ?>
 With that¿

Comment: I don't know how use this code or where. sorry.i'm designer and i'm learning. Can you help me?

Comment: @vektor, Sorry I was out. Do you still need help?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add `<br>` after a "," you can do this:

```
$text = preg_replace("/,/", "<br>", get_post_meta($postid, 'colors', true));
```

Comment: Why regex for a simple string replacement? It would work, but `str_replace()` would suffice.

Comment: You are right but I always use regex thats why I use preg_replace.

Comment: Ok, though that raises another question: why do you _always_ use regex? :-p

Answer (score 0):

```
str_replace(", "    ,    ", <br  />"   ,  $string) ;
```

The format is ("from",  "to" ,  "what")